# JToken get length of array

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath

I have JSON string:

```
var jsonString = "{ rawRequest: { asset: ['123', '456'] } }";
```

And I have mapping param:

```
var param = "rawRequest.asset.length";
```

And I need to get count of array items:

```
JToken token = JToken.Parse(jsonString);
JToken valueToken = token.SelectToken($"$.{param}");
var count = valueToken.Value<int>(); // = 2
```

but `valueToken = null` if `param = "rawRequest.asset"` everything works fine.

How can I get length of array with using JToken? Maybe I need to modify `param` somehow?

Comment: An array length function in JsonPATH is not implemented by Json.NET, see [Unable to use JSONPath expressions like @.length #1318](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1318).  You will have to implement something yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your JToken to "JArray" and get the items count.
Of course, if the path is invalid or does not target an array, the cast will fail.

You can then do the following :

```
int count = (valueToken as JArray)?.Count ?? -1;
```

And get -1 if invalid.

Comment: unfotunatelly I need to get length via param `"rawRequest.asset.length"` or `"count(rawRequest.asset)"`. So my question was is there default way to parse length of array or I need to write some code to parse it?

Comment: I don't think you can do others "actions" than "select" with the path directly. So yes, you'll have to parse it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your code like this

```
var jsonString = "{ rawRequest: ['123', '456'] }";

var param = "rawRequest";

JToken token = JToken.Parse(jsonString);
var valueToken = token.SelectToken(param).Count();

Console.WriteLine(valueToken);
```

Comment: I need to get length via param "rawRequest.asset.length" or "count(rawRequest.asset)" or something else. So my question was is there default way to parse length of array or I need to write some code to parse it?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: The bellow solution was provided by [mdhalgara](https://github.com/mdhalgara) on that [github issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1318) which was linked by [dbc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc)

---

First let's fix your sample `jsonString` in order to have a valid one

```
var jsonString = "{ rawRequest: { asset: ['123', '456'] }}";
```

Then modify your `param` to select all elements under `asset`

```
var param = "rawRequest.asset[*]";
```

Finally change the `SelectToken` to `SelectTokens` on which you can call a `Count`

```
var count = token.SelectTokens(param).Count();
```

[DotnetFiddle link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8FAnOp)